# How to determine if the user tabbed out of a quantity field using knockout?

Tags: knockoutjs, magento2.3.5

I've got a 3rd party module that is showing configurable product details in a grid (i.e. it shows a list of the simple options next to the price of the simple and a qty field, all in a table format).

What we've noticed is that tabbing does not move you from one qty field to the next. Specifically, when you change the qty field and press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key knockout would trigger a change event which reloads the table.

Is there a way of telling that the change event was triggered by the user tabbing out of the qty field? If so, is there a way of automatically placing the user into the next qty field?

For reference, here is the generated html:

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: order_qty, event: {change: function(data, event) { $parent.updateInputQty() }}, attr: {'data-product-id': id, name: 'qty[' + id + ']'}" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" maxlength="12" value="0" data-product-id="443865" name="qty[443865]">
```

And the change function is:

```
updateInputQty: function () {
    this.canUpdateQty(true);
    this.calculateTotal();
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by detecting if the tab key (keyCode 9) triggered the event, something like this should help:

```
function(data, event) {
  if (event.keycode && event.keyCode == 9) {
    // Handle tab event here
  } else {
    // Handle other event here
  }
}
```

Comment: Will I need to change the generate html to pass data and event into the function?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by generated, you should have a HTML template you can edit. In your code data and event are already added - `change: function(data, event)`